# Multiple Mysql Connections from Docker -> Socket Error

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, mariadb, windows-server-2016

I currently try to migrate from VMs to Docker Windows Containers. Containers are hosten on a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. The OS is installed on a physical root computer hosted by Hetzner. My Docker Containers contain a console app, written in c#, performaning updates on a MariaDB database, hosted in google-cloud.

Before every console app ran in a seperated VM with its own ipv4. Now they run in a container and getting the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'A.C' threw an exception. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Authentication to host '##.##.##.##' for user '####' using 
method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: 
Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.AuthenticationFailed(Exception ex)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnection.Open()
   at ServiceStack.OrmLite.OrmLiteConnectionFactory.OpenDbConnection()
   at A.C.b()
   at A.C..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at A.C.A()
   at A.b..ctor()
   at A.a.A()
   at A.d.A(String[] )
   at A.d.a[A](String[] )
   at A.A.A(String[] )
```

Docker uses a NAT network. Hence I think there is a problem with the connection regarding to multiple connections from the same IP.

Have anyone of you had similiar experience or knows how to fix this? Im a little bit stucked and glad for any help. Thanks in advance.

If you have any more questions regarding my setup or anything else please let me know.

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a common problem in MySql.Data; see the comment from Rui Fan at the end of [bug 76597](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597) for a potential workaround.